# iPhone 6 screen burn

Tags: iphone

Well basically my iPhone 6 is showing imprinted images in the background, like from previous applications and such. Basically screen ghosting.

Here are some images:

[image]

[image]

In this case it is impressing the home screen, but it sometimes shows previous apps and such.

What is this issue related to is it hardware or display? Please if anyone has gone through this shine a light because it's really frustrating.

Comment: I would say this could be more of a hardware problem ( I could be wrong). Did you experience any touch-screen insensivity, or irregular irresponisveness?

Comment: Not at all, everything is responsive.

Comment: I am unfortunately not an iOS or iPhone user, but is there an option in let's say General Settings called Display calibration or something similar?

Comment: There isn't one, what might this be for?

Comment: I just had an idea that it could be something to do with LCD calibration. Anyway, did you have any issues before? Did your phone suffer a fall, pressure, heat, or anything like that?

Comment: I've had some similar issues, though never to the extent of yours. Two suggestions: firstly, take a screenshot to see if your phone is trying to display those images. This will tell us where the problem lies. Secondly, restart the phone (yes, I know how it sounds). While the display is off, hold it under a bright light to see if the ghosting is still there.

Comment: @Thebro21, well I just bought the phone Certified Refurbished. I already ordered a new screen/lcd so hopefully that's the issue otherwise i wasted my money.

Comment: @agentroadkill I am unable to see any ghosting, kind of impossible because the ghosting is very light. Also, the ghosting shows when booting up the phone(the white screen with the apple logo)

Comment: Also I doubt it is a hardware problem,  because when i screen share my iPhone onto my mac it doesn't show ghosting, but it does on actual mobile phone.

Comment: Do you mean you do think it's a hardware problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an Apple Store close to you definitely go in and/or book an appointment with a Genius. They will be able to take a look at it and advise you what has caused it. If it is hardware failure and your phone is within warranty, they will generally replace the screen for you on the spot for no charge. More often than not even if you are out of warranty, they will still replace it for free or for a much reduced price.

I agree with the others that this is a hardware issue with the LCD panel.

Comment: Well is either a hardware problem or LCD problem, that is what i am trying to figure out. If problem is LCD is fine because i can replace the screen/lcd myself. Although if it's a hardware problem it won't be so good for me.

Answer (score 1):

Definetly a LCD problem. By now I believe you have solved it, but that ghosting effect is a result of applying too much pressure on your phone's screen and because of that you can see the imprint of your app screen. Replacing LCD fixes that for sure, but I wouldn't be bothered with that, I barely noticed it myself. :D

Comment: Ghosting isn't always a result of applying too much pressure.

Answer (score 1):

Im having this problem right now but if you notice that the ghosting has maybe a blue-ish tint or is in the shape of the internal battery, its definitely an expanded battery problem. That happened to me and when i took it in they said it was clear signs of a expanded battery. It was pretty beyond repair so they just gave me a new one. (if your battery is draining super slow too thats a big sign of an expanded battery)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're describing, where previous images or app interfaces appear as faint "ghosts" in the background, is commonly referred to as "screen ghosting" or "image retention." This issue is typically related to the display hardware or screen technology and can be caused by several factors:

**Burn-in:** Some display technologies, particularly older ones like OLED, are susceptible to burn-in. Burn-in occurs when certain pixels on the screen degrade or age faster than others due to prolonged display of static images or high-contrast elements. As a result, remnants of those images can persist even after they have been removed from the screen.

**Image Retention:** Image retention is a temporary version of burn-in, where previously displayed images leave a temporary residue on the screen. It can happen when images or UI elements are displayed for extended periods and cause a temporary "imprint" on the screen. In most cases, this fades over time.

**Hardware Issue:** Sometimes, screen ghosting can be attributed to a hardware issue with the display panel itself, such as a malfunctioning screen driver or damaged screen components.

**Overheating:** Overheating of the device, especially in older models, can exacerbate screen issues. Heat can affect the longevity of display components and potentially lead to image retention or ghosting.